# Mod_evasive default parameters

Tags: ddos, apache2

I have configured  **mod_evasive** with below configuration. I dont understand difference  between *DOSPageCount* and *DOSSiteCount*.

```
<IfModule mod_evasive20.c>
  DOSHashTableSize 3097
  DOSPageCount 30
  DOSSiteCount 80
  DOSPageInterval 5
  DOSSiteInterval 5
  DOSBlockingPeriod 10

</IfModule>
```

So my question after how many request it will block my IP?

Answer (score 0):

Here are the Relevant Descriptions:

```
# This is the threshhold for the number of requests for the same page (or
# URI) per page interval.  Once the threshhold for that interval has been
# exceeded, the IP address of the client will be added to the blocking
# list.
DOSPageCount        2

# This is the threshhold for the total number of requests for any object by
# the same client on the same listener per site interval.  Once the
# threshhold for that interval has been exceeded, the IP address of the
# client will be added to the blocking list.
DOSSiteCount        50

# The interval for the page count threshhold; defaults to 1 second
# intervals.
DOSPageInterval     1

# The interval for the site count threshhold; defaults to 1 second
# intervals.
DOSSiteInterval     1
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer by [Casperx3](https://serverfault.com/users/876614/casperx3) is straight out of the documentation and is pretty much self explanatory.

To answer your specific question on "after how many request it will block my IP" keeping in mind your configs, below is the explanation

1. For DOSPageCount and DOSPageInterval config --> If 30 requests have already been made in a duration of 5 seconds for the same page/URL, the 31st request will get denied and your IP will be blocked
2. For DOSSiteCount and DOSSiteInterval config --> If 80 requests have already been made in a duration of 5 seconds for any page/URL for your application, the 81st request will get denied and your IP will be blocked
3. For DOSBlockingPeriod config --> Once your IP is blocked, it will take 10 seconds to get unblocked. If any request is made within the 10 second window, the timer is reset